# "Ok Glass" to pass to other Activity

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk, voice-recognition

For example:

I'm in an Activity, then, when I say "Ok glass" (or other words if it is possible),  I want to go to other Activity.

The voice command, here, is like an action to pass to other Activity.

¿Is it possible on Glass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use voice commands on google glass you must follow [this](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/voice) steps

Also dont forget to add development permission:
  `<usespermissionandroid:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT"/>`